# Insert a variable into a SQL statement

Tags: mysql, sql, r

Im having a dataframe that looks like this:

```
city <- c("Alkmaar", "Den Haag")
df <- data.frame(city)
```

What I would like to do now is write values into a mysql database. Therefore I do the following:

```
 library(DBI)
 con <- dbConnect(RMySQL::MySQL(),
                dbname = "match_predictions",
                host = "109.237.221.34",
                port = 3306,
                user = "**",
                password = "***")


 for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
  var1 <- city[i]
 dbGetQuery(con, "INSERT INTO weather(city) VALUES(var1)")
 }
```

But this trows an error:

```
  Error in .local(conn, statement, ...) : 
  could not run statement: Unknown column 'var1' in 'field list'
```

Any thoughts on how i can insert a variable into the database?

Comment: You can use something like `sprintf("INSERT INTO weather(city) VALUES(%s)", var1)`. If `var1` is a vector of cities, a vector of queries will be returned (one for each city).

Comment: Thanks @steveb but if I run: example <- dbSendQuery(con, sprintf("INSERT INTO weather(city) VALUES(%s)", x)) I still get the error: Error in .local(conn, statement, ...) : 
  could not run statement: Unknown column 'h' in 'field list'. (this of course with h defined as variable

Comment: It worked for me, I was able to build the string `"INSERT INTO weather(city) VALUES(Alkmaar)"`.  In your case, I don't know what `x` is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use paste0 to write the query for each city.  I added in the single quotes and then you just need to make sure that you escape any single quotes in the city names if that occurs.

```
for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
  var1 <- city[i]
  # excape single quotes
  var2 <- gsub("\\'", "\\'\\'", var1)
  dbGetQuery(con, paste0("INSERT INTO weather(city) VALUES('", var2, "')"))
}
```

Comment: Awesome! I am glad that it worked.  I run into this all the time hence the added attention to the single quotes :)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
library(DBI)
 con <- dbConnect(RMySQL::MySQL(),
                dbname = "match_predictions",
                host = "109.237.221.34",
                port = 3306,
                user = "**",
                password = "***")


 for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
  var1 <- city[i]
 dbGetQuery(con, cat("INSERT INTO weather(city) VALUES(", var1 <- city[i], ")"))
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the `dbGetQuery` line in your code with the `dbGetQuery` line shown here:

```
library(gsubfn)

fn$dbGetQuery(con, "INSERT INTO weather(city) VALUES('$var1')")
```